# Basic auth preventing page from loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

- Node Version: 7.8.0
- Protractor Version: 5.1.2
- Angular Version: 1.5.3
- Browser(s): Chrome 59
- Operating System and Version OSX 10.12.5

My site requires basic auth. This has been running fine as I pass the credentials through the home page url.

```
browser.get(`https://${username}:${password}@${hosts.baseURL}`);
```

However after todays auto update to Chrome 59 this stopped working. The page will not load. I get a blank page.

I found if I remove the credentials from the url the page will load fine but I must enter the credentials manually. Not sure the basic auth is the problem.
Anyone know the possible cause/solution for this?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
Turns out @mplungjan was correct. The flag to change the way basic auth worked in chrome was added in Chrome v58 and enforced in v59. This basically broke all my tests. After several ocomplaints it will be changed back in v61 and maybe v60. To get chrome working with basic auth the way it used to function prior to the change add the following to the chrome options:

```
chromeOptions: {
  args: ['--disable-blink-features=BlockCredentialedSubresources']
}
```

Comment: I suggest you complain on the link I gave. They may change their minds :) Alternatively accept that they have your and your visitors' safety in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's gone:

[Evaluate dropping legacy and credentialed subresource requests.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=435547)

Enable blocking of subresource requests whose URLs include credentials.

This patch flips the 'BlockCredentialedSubresources' flag to 'stable', and
ties it to a feature flag in //content that we can use as a kill switch if
it turns out that enterprise usage of the feature is higher than we hope
(the overall numbers still look reasonably low[1]).

Intent: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/lx-U_JR2BF0

Comment: This change hit us pretty hard.  We have a number of scenarios where we use Selenium to test different users accessing web applications over the corporate intranet with windows authentication.  We use these tests to confirm the users `have|don't have` access to urls, panels on pages, etc..  Anyway, thanks for the information - it took awhile to figure out what the actual problem was and why it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

you may work around this by using a proxy such as [browsermob-proxy](https://bmp.lightbody.net/) to handle basic authentication.

Here are quick instructions to do so:

1. download and extract browsermob-proxy
2. configure protractor to use a proxy: in protractor.conf.js, add a proxy section to your capabilities, eg:

   ```
   capabilities: {
       browserName: 'chrome',
       'chromeOptions': {
           'args': ['disable-infobars=true'],
           'prefs': {'credentials_enable_service': false}
       },
       'proxy': {
            'proxyType': 'manual',
            'httpProxy': 'localhost:8888',
            'sslProxy': 'localhost:8888'  
       },
    },
   ```
3. start and configure browsermob proxy before running your specs with protractor (8080 is the port used to control browsermob via its REST api, 8888 is the actual proxy port):

   ```
   $ browsermob-proxy --use-littleproxy false
   $ curl -s --request POST --url http://localhost:8080/proxy?port=8888
   $ curl -s --request POST --url \
     http://localhost:8080/proxy/8888/auth/basic/your.site.com \
     --data '{"username":"yourUsername","password":"yourPassword"}' \
     -H 'Content-type: application/json'
   ```

This should work nicely (it does for me), as long as you don't rely on websockets.

Note that you may also control browsermob-proxy from your scripts, using a node module such as [browsermob-proxy-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browsermob-proxy-api).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following workaround:

1. First I pass the credentials in the URL

   ```
   browser.get(`https://${username}:${password}@${hosts.baseURL}`);
   ```

   so at this point I'm authenticated.
2. Then I do a second call passing the URL without credentials

   ```
   browser.get(`https://${hosts.baseURL}`);
   ```

So in the end I have:

```
    browser.get(`https://${username}:${password}@${hosts.baseURL}`);
    browser.get(`https://${hosts.baseURL}`);
```

---

Same thing it's possible with any testing framework (I'm using both Protractor and Codeception).

So for example in Codeception it would be, if the URL with auth credentials is defined in the .yml file:

```
    $I->amOnPage('/');
    $I->amOnUrl(`https://`.$baseURL);
```

Or just

```
    $I->amOnUrl(`https://`.$username.`:`.$password.`@`.$baseURL);
    $I->amOnUrl(`https://`.$baseURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to add `disable-blink-features=BlockCredentialedSubresources` to `chromeOptions` in my `config.js` and it file worked for me!

**config.js:**

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

capabilities: {
    "browserName": 'chrome',
"chromeOptions": {
 args:['--disable-blink-features=BlockCredentialedSubresources']
},
specs: ['filename.js']
}
};
```

**In spec:**

```
browser.get('http://username:password@domain.com');
```

I made sure to keep credentials with URL. I tried to take it out at first and it failed, then added back in and worked great.